# Why do we have $p ( x , y | z ) = p ( x | z ) p ( y | x , z )$

Tags: probability-theory, bayes-theorem

Could anyone derive or explain why the formula $p ( x , y   |   z ) = p ( x   |   z ) p ( y   |   x , z )$ is true?

Comment: Have you tried write the definition of $P(A|B)$ and the  check the formula?

Comment: No indication about what you tried, how can we help?

Comment: $$  P(x,y|z) = \frac{P(x\cap y)(\cap z)}{P(z)}
$$
$$  P(x,y|z) P(z) = P(x\cap y)(\cap z) 
 $$
$$  \frac {P(x,y|z) P(z)}{P(z)} = P(x\cap y)(\cap z) 
 $$
$$  P(x,y|z) = P(x\cap y)(\cap z) 
 $$

Comment: @Siemens Indeed one can run in circles as you do in your comment, for a long time (but note that identities 1 and 2 hold provided one replaces the absurd P(x∩y)(∩z) by P(x∩y∩z), while 3 and 4 are squarely wrong). Is this all you tried? So you never even considered p(x|z)p(y|x,z)?

Answer (score 5):

**Take the defintion** (for $P(B) \neq 0$):
$$P(A|B) := \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
Just use that for every term and you will see that the equation holds.

**Edit**
I'll make it clearer and use your notation:
$$p(x,y|z)=\frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(z)}$$
and
$$p(y|x,z)=\left(\frac{p(y,x,z)}{p(x,z)}= \right)\frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(x,z)}.$$
And this holds by definition.
There is no computation done here.

Comment: i know this formula but when i use i can not prove that is true.

Comment: @Siemens Hint: $(x\cap y)\cap z = (x\cap z)\cap y$

Comment: for example P(x,y|z) = P(x|z) * P(y|z) then 

P(x)P(z|x) P(y) P(z|X) i stuck here

Comment: i i can wrote this formula correctly for you guys to see what I've done

Comment: @Siemens No.  $P(x,y\mid z) = \dfrac{P(x,y,z)}{P(z)}$.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started. We use: $\mathsf P(\alpha\mid \beta)\;\mathsf P(\beta)=\mathsf P(\alpha\cap \beta)$

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P ( x \cap y \mid z ) & = \frac{\mathsf P((x\cap y)\cap z)}{\mathsf P(z)} & \text{if } \mathsf P(z)\neq 0
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\mathsf P((x\cap z)\cap y)}{\mathsf P(z)}
\end{align}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: i i can wrote this formula correctly for you guys to see what I've done. I already did this step.

Comment: $$  P(x,y|z) = \frac{P(x\cap y)(\cap z)}{P(z)}
$$
$$  P(x,y|z) P(z) = P(x\cap y)(\cap z) 
 $$
$$  \frac {P(x,y|z) P(z)}{P(z)} = P(x\cap y)(\cap z) 
 $$
$$  P(x,y|z) = P(x\cap y)(\cap z) 
 $$

Comment: @Siemens  No; try again.  Aside from misplacing the bracket in the RHS of first line, you divided by $P(z)$ on the LHS of the third line without also doing so to the RHS.